# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given. in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ip

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

---

Here is my code:

```
 Route::get('/user/ip', function(Request $request) {
    $ip =$request->ip();
    //return $ip;
    return Curl::to('https://ipapi.co/'.$ip.'/json/')->get();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar question. Your code should be as:

```
Route::get('/user/ip', function(Request $request) {
    $ip =$request->ip();
    //return $ip;
    return response()
        ->json(Curl::to('https://ipapi.co/'.$ip.'/json/')->get()
    );
});
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create the api that way.

On Laravel 5 you can create your route on routes->api then Laravel will know that is a api route.

Example:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::get('/engineers', 'EngineerController@index');
```

The Engineers Collection:

```
class EngineerCollection extends ResourceCollection {

    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection
        ];
    }
}
```

And the EnginersController index function:

```
 public function index()
    {
        return new EngineerCollection(Engineers::all());
    }
```

And then go to your app:

http://myapp.com/api/engineers