# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given. in laravel

Tags: laravel

What is this error?

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing
>   __toString(), "boolean" given.

```
public function search()
    {
        $keyword = request('search');
        $articles = Article::search($keyword)->latest()->get();
        $courses = Course::search($keyword)->latest()->get();
        return $articles or $courses;
    }
```

What should I say instead of **or**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Response content must be a string or object implementing \_\_toString(), "boolean" given. in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667658/the-response-content-must-be-a-string-or-object-implementing-tostring-bool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `or` is conditional operator which will give boolean in result,Use ternary operator to achieve, like this.

```
public function search()
{
    $keyword = request('search');
    $articles = Article::search($keyword)->latest()->get();
    $courses = Course::search($keyword)->latest()->get();
    return $articles ? $articles : ($courses ? $courses : '' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `boolean` instead of a `string`. You need to change it to something like this to make it work:

```
return $articles->isEmpty() ? $courses : $articles;
```

Or:

```
return response()->json($articles->isEmpty() ? $courses : $articles);
```